# XMPPFramework on iOS -xmppRoomDidDestroy: not getting called

Tags: iphone, ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I'm developing an iPhone app using the XMPP framework for iOS/OSX and I'm using the XEP-0045 extension (multi-user chat).  I've got the room creating and configuring successfully and I am able to invite other users and chat with them.  The problem arises when I go to destroy the room I've created.  I've followed the code-path that gets executed inside the framework and I've figured out why the framework isn't firing the method, but I'm not sure how it would ever fire the method given the behavior I'm seeing.

That behavior is as follows:

1) I request that the room be destroyed by calling [room destroyRoom]

2) I then see that the XMPPRoom class sets up its XMPPIDResponse tracker to watch for the "result" iq stanza that the server will send back saying it's successfully deleted the room.

3) (Here is where the problem arises) I receive a presence stanza from the room saying it's now unavailable (since I, too, am an occupant of the room) and the framework then clears the response tracker and calls -xmppRoomDidLeave:.

4) The server then sends back the "result" iq stanza saying that the room was successfully deleted, but no one is listening anymore.  This results in the call to xmppRoomDidDestroy being missed.

This behavior is consistent with what I've read in the XEP-0045 definition and, given that, I'm not sure how the -xmppRoomDidDestroy: delegate would ever get called.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Hi Zachary I am having exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution?

-xmppRoomDidDestroy is called when there are more members in the group when is destroyed, but in my environment the problem is that I should only destroy the room where I am the last member of it...

Comment: Hey Lightman.  I know that this is late, but hopefully it will be helpful.  Unfortunately, I was not able to find a solution.  I ended up having to use my own XMPPIDResponseTracker to watch for it and call the delegate myself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is my solution:

In XMPPRoom method

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence
```

replace

```
[responseTracker removeAllIDs];
```

with:

```
if ([x elementForName:@"destroy"]) {
    NSArray *allKeys = [responseTracker allIDs];
    for (NSString *key in allKeys) {
        SEL aSel = [responseTracker selectorForElementID:key];
        if (aSel != @selector(handleDestroyRoomResponse:withInfo:)) {
            [responseTracker removeID:key];
        }
    }
} else {
    [responseTracker removeAllIDs];
}
```

In XMPPIDTracker.h add declaration for new public methods

```
- (NSArray *)allIDs;

- (SEL)selectorForElementID:(NSString *)elementID;
```

Also in XMPPBasicTrackingInfo interface add

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) SEL selector;
```

In XMPPIDTracker.m add two public methods

```
- (NSArray *)allIDs {
    return [dict allKeys];
}

- (SEL)selectorForElementID:(NSString *)elementID {
    id <XMPPTrackingInfo> info = [dict objectForKey:elementID];
    if ([info isKindOfClass:[XMPPBasicTrackingInfo class]]) {
        return [(XMPPBasicTrackingInfo *)info selector];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

At the end in the @implementation XMPPBasicTrackingInfo add

```
@synthesize selector;
```

Basicaly this code removes all response trackers except handleDestroyRoomResponse:withInfo: because we need this hander to respond on IQ destroy stanza.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Hi, I have followed steps given by you but its not working. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with lastest `XMPPFramework 3.6.6`.

Here is the solution:

Still use `destroyRoom` function, `xmppStream:didReceivePresence:` and `xmppRoomDidLeave:` will be called, test by add `NSLog` inside both delegate, then i use Spark(Windows version) to destory a room, the Xcode console print the following text:

```
<presence xmlns="jabber:client" type="unavailable" from="wei@conference.10.50.200.94/admin" to="admin@10.50.200.94/iOS">
    <x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user">
        <item affiliation="none" role="none"></item>
        <destroy>
            <reason>destroy room</reason>
        </destroy>
    </x>
</presence>
```

I use the `<destroy>` element to determine the `destroyRoom` action.

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence
{
    /*
     <presence xmlns="jabber:client" type="unavailable" from="wei@conference.10.50.200.94/admin" to="admin@10.50.200.94/iOS"><x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user"><item affiliation="none" role="none"></item><destroy><reason>destroy room</reason></destroy></x></presence>
     */
    // NSLog(@"%s %@", __FUNCTION__, presence);
    if ([presence.fromStr containsString:@"conference"]) {
        NSXMLElement *x = [presence elementForName:@"x"];
        if (x) {
            NSXMLElement *destroy = [x elementForName:@"destroy"];
            if (destroy) {
                XMPPJID *roomJID = presence.from.bareJID;
                // TODO: do something with the roomJID
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But `XMPPFramework` send a empty `<destory/>` element, i guess the openfire server simply ignore the `<destroy/>` and response `<presence>..</presence>` without `<destroy>`.

Modify the `destroyRoom` function in `XMPPFramework` or implement the following delegate to add a destroy reason.

```
- (XMPPIQ *)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender willSendIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
{
    /*
     <iq type="set" to="weixin@conference.10.50.200.94" id="BCF55C6A-9C5E-4740-BE6A-63E17B5C58F6"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner"><destroy></destroy></query></iq>
     */
    if ([iq isSetIQ]) {
        NSXMLElement *query = [iq elementForName:@"query" xmlns:XMPPMUCOwnerNamespace];
        if (query) {
            NSXMLElement *destroy = [query elementForName:@"destroy"];
            if (destroy) {
                NSXMLElement *reason = [destroy elementForName:@"reason"];
                if (!reason) {
                    reason = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"reason" stringValue:@"destroy reason"];
                    [destroy addChild:reason];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return iq;
}
```